# How do I remove the faulty version of Ubuntu from my PC?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu 14 on my PC, but it failed to recognise the keyboad, so was of no use.  I therefore reinstalled Ubuntu, using the option to overwrite all files, but it appears to have created a second OS on the PC.  Now, when I boot up, I get the faulty version.  If I then press the reset button, I get the good version.  Next time I start the PC, I'll get the faulty version again.  How do I stop this from happening?  I guess the answer is to delete the faulty version, but I thought I'd done that by reinstalling, but obviously not.

Here is the output of `sudo parted -l`:

```
ATA Maxtor 6B200P0 (scsi) Disk 
/dev/sda: 204GB Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B 
Partition Table: msdos 

Number Start  End   Size   Type     FileSystem        Flags 
1      1049kB 198GB 198GB  primary  ext4              boot 
2      198GB  204GB 6210MB extended 
3      198GB  204GB 6210MB logical  linux swap (v1)
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo parted -l`?

Comment: @Gary
Model: ATA Maxtor 6B200P0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 204GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Number Start End Size Type FileSystem Flags
1 1049kB 198GB 198GB primary ext4 boot
2 198GB 204GB 6210MB extended
3 198GB 204GB 6210MB logical linux swap (v1)

Comment: I'm not seeing how there could be two different copies of Ubuntu present given the formatting of the drive. When you say you get the "faulty" version on some boots, what does that mean? Does it fail to boot?

Comment: @Gary: My thoughts exactly.  There is only one version being shown.  When I did the first installation, I set a password.  When I did the second installation, I didn't set a password.  When I boot up first of all, I get asked for the password.  I enter the password, get through to the startup screen, the keyboard isn't recognised and the program doesn't run properly.  When I reset the PC, I get straight in to the startup screen (no password needed) run the program and it's fine.

Comment: Does the installation keep oscillating between asking for your password and not working, and simply working fine, after each reset? Also, are you rebooting or shutting down?

Comment: @Gary: When I switch on the PC from cold, I get the faulty installation.  If I reset, I get the good one.  Having got the good one, I've never reset again to see if I get the faulty one - I'll have to go down to the Museum and try it out.  I'll let you know what I find.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember reading, you may be able to use a tool such as "Grub Customizer" to change the order of the boot, so you get the one you want. Would you be able to also boot into the good version and then remove all files from the bad partition and format the drive (GParted) and then boot only the good one?

Having troubles in the past related to this, I personally found that backing up all your data and then a fresh install is the way to go. I used the USB flash pen and all was fine my end.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Phil, but there is only one version of the installation showing, so I don't have anything to change. I'm begining to think that I may have to "nuke" the hard drive again and then restart the installation and hope that, this time, it goes straight through without any errors.

Comment: Hi Brian, oh I see. Sorry to hear that. Hope that you sort it out though.

Answer (score -2):

You might have installed the new installation side-by-side of the original installation. I would recommend to do:

1. a backup of all your data (unencrypted)
2. a complete removal of all partitions on the hard drive, using a live Ubuntu CD or USB drive.
3. Do a fresh installation (that'll hopefully function as normal).

Comment: And what about his data?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought I did... told Ubuntu just to use the whole hard drive, delete everything (i.e. the original installation) and start again.  There wasn't any data on it anyway as I'd "nuked" the previous installations.  Just now, I'll walk down to the Museum where the PC is located and download the output of sudo parted -l as requested by Gary.  Thank you for your help and suggestions - much appreciated.

Comment: This is the output of sudo parted -l
Unfortunately, as I try to post it, all my formatting vanishes.

Model: ATA Maxtor 6B200P0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 204GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Number Start End Size Type FileSystem Flags
1 1049kB 198GB 198GB primary ext4 boot
2 198GB 204GB 6210MB extended
3 198GB 204GB 6210MB logical linux swap (v1)